# Renaming my Navigation Term Set will set it as "Available for Tagging"

Tags: 2013, development, navigation, managed-navigation, enterprise-wiki

I have sharepoint 2013 on-premises farm. and i am facing this scenario inside my enterprise wiki site collection:-

1. I created a new enterprise wiki site collection. and it comes with navigation term set created automatically.
2. now under the root site, i created a new sub-site (named wiki123) of type enterprise wiki also.
3. and inside the subsite >> Site Setting >> Navigation.
4. i define that it have a managed navigation, and i click to create a new Term Set as follow:-

[image]

5. i save the navigation settings changes.
6. now at that time the term set (named wiki123 Navigation) will have the following settings (where it is set for navigation, but not available for tagging):-

[image]
7. but when i went to the term store management, and i rename the term set, as follow:-

[image]
i noticed that after renaming the term set, the term set will have the following setting (where it will be set as available for tagging):-

[image]

so can anyone adivce on these points please:-

1. is this a bug in sharepoint? as renaming a term set should not change the "available for tagging " check box, is this correct?
2. generally speaking if i want to use a term set for navigation, should it be set as "available for tagging"??

Answer (score 2):

I have tested in SharePoint RTM and SharePoint with July 2017 CU (15.0.4945.1000), but cannot reproduce your issue.

Here are my test steps and results:

1. Open an Enterprise wiki site and create a term set using “Create Term Set” option in the navigation settings page.
2. Open Term Store Management Tool to check the term set. The “Available for Tagging” option is checked by default.
3. Uncheck the “Available for Tagging” option and save.
4. Open General tab and change the term set name and save.
5. Back to Intended Use tab and check the “Available for Tagging” option. It still is unchecked.

What is the version of your SharePoint server? Ensure you have save the settings for the term set. Install the SharePoint CU for a try.

Comment: thanks for the reply. our farm have a lower CU `15.0.4787.1000` which is Jan 2016. Now i do not want to upgrade the farm to the latest CU at this stage as it will require valuable testing time to check that everything is working well after the upgrade. so currently what i can do to fix this on our farm which have lower CU ?  so should i manually un-check the “Available for Tagging” and move forward?? or i need to keep this check box checked? second point what is the effect of checking/un-checking the "Available for tagging" for the navigation term set?